# ESTA was not approved but I have a valid visa

Tags: visas, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, tourist-visas

I have dual citizenship (Israel, Switzerland).  I am 63 years old and I was born in Syria, but I have not been there and I have not been there or in any country for more than 40 years and I have not been in any other Arab country (I am a Jew).

I have a US visa valid for another 10 months.

In any case, I applied for an ESTA and for an unknown reason I received an
answer: "You are not authorized to travel to the United States under the
Visa Waiver Program."

It is important to note that I have never been denied a visa, never stayed longer than allowed, and do not have a criminal record in any country.

I must mention that I still have avisa.

I plan on going on a trip with my family in October. Will I have a problem entering with my Israeli passport?

Comment: I did not have an ESTA before, only VISA (ie still has).
I am 63 years old and I was born in Syria, but I have not been there and I have not been there or in any country for more than 40 years and I have not been in any other Arab country (I am a Jew).

Comment: Why were you applying for an ESTA if you have a visa?

Comment: ESTA means you don't need a visa. But you got a visa. There is no problem. Would it be possible they can't give you ESTA *because* you still got a valid visa?

Comment: @Mast Nope, got an ESTA with a valid visa, and on the same passport (unlike here, I guess).  Of course, theoretically it might be different with a B1/B2 visa, though I doubt it.

Answer (score 25):

If you and/or your father were born in Syria, then it's likely that you are considered a national of Syria - at least by Syria itself.  This is true regardless of whether you consider yourself a Syrian citizen or not.

Syrian Nationals are NOT eligible to use the Visa Waiver Program, which is probably why your application was rejected.

However this does not affect the status of your visa.  If you have an active, non-expired visa then there is no reason to suspect you will not be allowed enter the US using that visa.

Answer (score 6):

The Visa Waiver Program (VWP) is for people who do not require a Visa (*[to waive](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/waive?s=t)* meaning "to refrain from insisting on").

The Electronic System for Travel Authorisation (ESTA) is a system whereby the USA determines whether you are eligible for the VWP before allowing you to fly.

As you have a visa, you don't need to enter under the VWP, which means you don't need an ESTA.

You should not have any problem entering with your visa and the passport it was issued for.